# impossible to find automatically the settings for this network proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, windows-8.1

I started a new computer up with Windows 8.1 inside and now I've to activate Windows. I tried to connect the computer to a Wi-Fi router, but there's a diagnostic problem.
I tried to resolve it automatically, but the computer can't solve the problem itself and it gives me the following message

"impossible to find automatically the settings for this network proxy"

So I googled the network problem and I found the following solution to execute from cmd

netsh winsock reset

netsh int ip reset

netsh advfirewall reset

Then I restarted the computer, but the error hadn't be solved.

Have you any ideas?
Could the error be a network card problem?

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me.

edit:

this is what I get from the command prompt with ipconfig

[image: this is what I get from the command prompt with ipconfig]

the problem:

[image: the problem:]

[image]

Comment: could you post an output of the `ipconfig /all` command ?

Comment: I suspect the wifi router should be having restricted access OR something firewall related problem!